# How to apply custom styles in a CMS page?

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, styles, hyva

I am trying to add custom styles on 404 CMS page. I added html on admin side of CMS 404 page. The html for 404 page is

```
<h1 class="no-route-section-one-heading heading"> {{trans'Excuse me! Page not found.'}}</h1>
    <div class="no-route-section-one">
    <p class="description"> {{trans'The page you were looking for was not found.'}} </p>
    <ul class="points-list">
    <li> {{trans'Check that you have entered the correct URL'}}</>
    <li> {{trans'If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is incorrect or not working'}}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <h1 class="no-route-section-two-heading heading"> {{trans 'What can I do?'}}  </h1>

    <div class="no-route-section-two">
    <p class="description"> {{trans'There are more ways you can get back on track with the Capital Store.'}} </p>
    <ul class="points-list">
    <li> {{trans'Go back to the previous page'}}</li>
    <li> {{trans'Use the search pages above to find the products you want'}}</li>
    <li> {{trans'Use these links:'}}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="no-route-button-links">
    <a class="home-page-link link" href="{{store url=""}}">{{trans'Go to home page'}} </a>
    <a class="profile-page-link link" href="{{store url="customer/account"}}">{{trans'Go to my profile'}} </a>
    </div>
```

After that, I have added my styles under app/design/frontend///web/tailwind/theme/pages/no-routes.css. The css styles are below

```
.heading {
    @apply text-slate;
    @apply text-4xl;
}

.no-route-section-one {
    @apply mt-6;
    @apply pb-8;
    @apply border-b;
    @apply border-grey-lighter;
    @apply border-solid;
}

.points-list {
    @apply mt-6;
}

.no-route-section-two-heading {
    @apply mt-6;
}

.no-route-section-two {
    @apply mt-6;
}

.no-route-button-links {
    @apply mt-8;
    @apply mb-20;
    @apply flex;
}

.home-page-link {
    @apply bg-blue;
    @apply text-white;
}

.profile-page-link {
    @apply bg-grey-light;
    @apply text-blue;
    @apply ml-2.5;
}

.link {
    @apply no-underline;
    @apply text-base;
    @apply align-middle;
    @apply text-center;
    @apply pt-3;
    @apply pb-3.5;
    @apply pr-12;
    @apply pl-12;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 810px) {
    .no-route-button-links {
        @apply flex-col;
        @apply mb-6;
    }

    .profile-page-link {
        @apply ml-0;
        @apply mt-2;
    }

}
```

However, I cannot see any styles changes when I navigate to 404 CMS page. I am pretty new to magento2 and still trying to understand how it works. But, this does not work. How can I apply my custom styles on a CMS page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can add the styles on the cms page directly.

   Your Custom Css
2. You have to import the custom CSS file to the 404 page via XML.